# Compare a user inputted number with a randomly generated number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a randomly generated number, ask the user to enter a number, then compare the two and then show a popup telling whether or not they match. This is my code

```js
     function myFunction() {
     var num=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

     }

     function myFunction1() {

     var secondInput = document.getElementById("demo1").value;


     if( num === secondInput)
     {
     window.alert("Same");
     }
     else
     {
     window.alert("Don't do that again  cvv");
     }
```

```html
     <button onclick="myFunction()">press the button to see the code</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>

     code: <input type="text" name="code" required/><br/><br/>

    <button onclick="myFunction1()">Compare</button> 
    <p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo1").value` now take a look in your HTML what kind of element is `demo1`

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: it is not working

Comment: How do you know that? Are you getting an error? If so, what line is the error on? What does the error say?

Comment: i run it and the page does not shows the popup. That is the reason i have a window alert even they are not the same numbers. But neither in this case shows something

Comment: because num is declared in another function.... Learn about scope

Comment: Can i do something?

Comment: When working with JavaScript in a browser, press F12 to show the developer tools. Then, click on the "console" tab. This is where error messages appear. You shouldn't expect us to do all the work here. You should post your question with as much information for others as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Please know that there were a couple of improvements:

- You referenced to `myFunction()` before the javascript is loaded.
- You need to keep the var `num` in global scope if you want to reference it in other places, without passing them as an argument.
- When comparing values, make sure to select the right input field and to convert the value string to a Number.

```js
var num;
function myFunction() {
  num=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
}
     
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', myFunction)
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener('click', myFunction1)

function myFunction1() {
 var secondInput = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
  if( num === +secondInput) {
     window.alert("Same");
  }
  else {
     window.alert("Don't do that again  cvv");
  }
}
```

```html
 <button id="button1" >press the button to see the code</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>

     code: <input id="demo1" type="text" name="code" required/><br/><br/>

    <button id="button2">Compare</button> 
    <p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define `num` in the global scope to be accessable by the two functions and you have to make the first function just show the number without generating a new number every time.

```js
 

var num;
function show() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = num;
}

 function randomizeAndCompare() {
  num = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
  if( num === secondInput){
   window.alert("Same");
  }
  else{
   window.alert("Don't do that again  cvv");
  }
}
```

```html
 

<button onclick="show()">press the button to see the code</button>
 <p id="demo"></p>

 code: <input type="text" name="code" required/><br/><br/>

<button onclick="randomizeAndCompare()">Compare</button> 
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tings here.

First, myFunction1() isn't closed. You should also rename it to something more meaningful, like "compareValue()". That way it is easier to read the code.

You also aren't making a comparison of the two numbers in your compareValue()-function. Your 'num' variable isn't defined. You are also trying to extract the user input value from the button.

See my suggestion for changes:

```
function generateRandom() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(1000 + 
    Math.random() * 9000);
}

function compareValues() {
    var num = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var input = document.getElementById("number").value;

    if( num === input)
    {
        window.alert("Same");
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert("Don't do that again  cvv");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="generateRandom()">press the button to see the code</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

code: <input id="number" type="text" name="code" required/><br/><br/>

<button onclick="compareValues()">Compare</button>    
<p id="demo1"></p>
```